# Is it necessary to await a single asynchronous call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If I'm returning the result of a single asynchronous function e.g. in a service between application layers, is there any difference between:

```
    public Task<byte[]> GetInsurancePolicyDocument(string itineraryReference)
    {
        return this.coreItineraryDocumentService.GetInsurancePolicyDocument(itineraryReference);
    }
```

And:

```
    public async Task<byte[]> GetInsurancePolicyDocument(string itineraryReference)
    {
        return await this.coreItineraryDocumentService.GetInsurancePolicyDocument(itineraryReference);
    }
```

Comment: Without more context, this answer is impossible to be answered. BTW, don't use async/await because it is cool. Use it when you do need it.

Comment: @LexLi, I disagree but its moot, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Clearly this function is doing I/O so I don't think I'm using async-await 'because it's cool'. The result of this and similar services eventually make their way to an MVC controller where they are awaited asynchronously (Task.WhenAll) before being stuck in a View-Model.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few very subtle differences in some cases - for example, if the original `Task` returns with a status of `Faulted` but with an `OperationCanceledException` then the `async` version would return a task with a status of `Canceled`... but unless you really need any of that subtlety, it would generally be better to go with your first code and avoid the (very slight) overhead of wrapping it.